# how to add a search box to forum in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have configured, wordpress forum. I have created several forums in the site.
Everthing is fine but there is no configuration to search previous form topics.
I use bbPress forum.

I have tried following but didnt see any difference.

```
<div class="bbp-search-form">
    <?php bbp_get_template_part( 'form', 'search'); ?>

</div>
```

I added above code to content-single-forum.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: this will create a general search box which can not search the forum content.

Comment: No it doesn't search forum content though post created by wordpress